# OpenGL 2D agents animation and scenario refresh

Tags: c++, opengl, animation

I'm trying to do a little game in 2D to learn how to do it and improve my programming skills. I programme the game using C++/C and OpenGL 3.0 with GLUT.
I so confused with some important concepts about animations and scenario refresh.

1. It's a good practice load all the textures only when the level begins ?
2. I choose a fps rate to 40 fps, should i redraw all the scenario and the agents in every frame or only the modifications ?
3. In an agent animation should i redraw all the entire agent or only the parts which changes from the past ?
4. If some part of the scene changes (one wall or something similar is destroyed) should i need to redraw all the entire scene or only the part which changes ?

Now my "game" works with a framerate of 40fps but the game has a **flickering** effect that looks really weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, creating and deleting textures/buffers every frame is a huge waste.
2. It's almost always cheaper to just redraw the entire scene. GPUs are built to do this, it's very fast.

   Reading the framebuffer from VRAM back to regular RAM and calculating the difference is going to be much slower, especially since OpenGL doesn't keep track of your "objects", it just takes a triangle at a time, rasterizes it, then forgets about it.
3. Depends on how you define the animation. If you're talking about sprite-like animation, where each frame is a separate image, then it's cheapest to just refer to the new texture and redraw.

   If you've got a texture atlas, update the texture coordinates and redraw, and if you're using shaders (you pretty much have to if you want to be OpenGL 3.0), you might be able to get away with a uniform that offsets texture coordinates.
4. Yeah, as I said before, the hardware is built to clear the screen and redraw everything.

And for a framerate, you should be using the monitor's refresh rate to avoid vertical tearing. Pretty much all monitors now are 60Hz, so 60fps is the most common "target" framerate.

Answer (score 1):

Choose either 30 or 60 fps as most modern monitors refresh in 60 Hz rate. So you have either 2 or 1 rendered frame per "monitor frame". This should reduce flickering effects. (I'm not 100% sure if you mean this with "flash effect".)

Regarding all other questions (which sound pretty much the same): In OpenGL rendering, redrawing everything is pretty common, as in most games almost the entire screen changes in every frame, for example if you're moving around. You *could* do a partial screen update, but it's very uncommon and more expensive on the CPU side, as you have to compute which parts to draw instead of just "draw everything".

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes

2-4. Yes - Hopefully this help you understand why you must...

Imagine you have 2 pieces of paper. The first paper you draw a stick man standing still, and show that to somebody.

The second paper while the user is looking at that paper you draw the same thing again but this time you move the arm a little bit.

Now you show them the second paper, as they look at the second paper you clear the first paper and draw the man moving his arm a little bit more.

This is pretty much how it works and is the reason you must always render the whole image regardless if nothing has changed.